# Amazon EC2: VPS/VDS or dedicated

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, dedicated-server

Are Amazon EC2 instances VPS/VDS or dedicated servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are virtual servers. More specifically, they are virtual servers running within the Xen hypervisor.